# Assigning function internal prototype to function prototype object

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.why is the following assignment false?

2.What can be the next way ?

```
var A = function(name) {
    this.name = name

    }

     A.prototype == A.__proto__; //false
```

Comment: It's not an assignment, but a comparison? Please clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the equation operator to compare two objects. In javascript you cannot compare two objects using the '==' operator.

Have a look here:
[Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)